# pandas groupby trying to optimse several steps

Tags: pandas-groupby

I've been trying to optimise a bokeh server to calculate live stats by selected country on Covid19.

I found myself repeating a groupby function to calculate new columns and was wondering, having selected the groupby, if I could then apply it in a similar way to .agg() on multiple columns ?

For example:

```
dfall = pd.DataFrame(db("SELECT * FROM C19daily"))
dfall.set_index(['geoId', 'date'], drop=False, inplace=True)
dfall = dfall.sort_index(ascending=True)
```

dfall.head()

```
                      id        date geoId  cases  deaths          auid
geoId date                                                            
AD    2020-03-03  70119  2020-03-03    AD      1       0  AD03/03/2020
      2020-03-14  70118  2020-03-14    AD      1       0  AD14/03/2020
      2020-03-16  70117  2020-03-16    AD      3       0  AD16/03/2020
      2020-03-17  70116  2020-03-17    AD      9       0  AD17/03/2020
      2020-03-18  70115  2020-03-18    AD      0       0  AD18/03/2020
```

I need to create new columns based on 'cases' and 'deaths' and applying various functions like cumsum(). Currently I do this the long way

```
dfall['ccases'] = dfall.groupby(level=0)['cases'].cumsum()
dfall['dpc_cases'] = dfall.groupby(level=0)['cases'].pct_change(fill_method='pad', periods=7)
    .....
dfall['cdeaths'] = dfall.groupby(level=0)['deaths'].cumsum()
dfall['dpc_deaths'] = dfall.groupby(level=0)['deaths'].pct_change(fill_method='pad', periods=7)
```

I tried to optimise the groupby call like this:-

```
with dfall.groupby(level=0) as gr:
    gr = g['cases'].cumsum()...
```

But the error suggest the class doesn't support this

```
AttributeError: __enter__
```

I thought I could use .agg({}) and supply dictionary

```
g = dfall.groupby(level=0).agg({'cc' : 'cumsum', 'cd' : 'cumsum'})
```

but that produces another error

```
pandas.core.base.SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported
```

I have plenty of other bits to optimise, I thought this python part would be the easiest and save a few ms!

Could anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid repeating `dfall.groupby(level=0)` you can just save it in a variable:

```py
gb = dfall.groupby(level=0)
gb_cases = gb['cases']

dfall['ccases'] = gb_cases.cumsum()
dfall['dpc_cases'] = gb_cases.pct_change(fill_method='pad', periods=7)
...
```

And to run multiple aggregations using a single expression, I think you can use [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation). But I have no clue whether it will be more performant or not. Either way, it's better to profile the code and improve the actual bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I don't know how I missed this clear shortcut. Probably I was distracted by trying to get  "with dfall.groupby(level=0) as gb:"